# Line Removal from .CSV via Batch Script

Tags: batch-file

I have 80+ uniquely named .csv files I need to remove the first 17 lines from. I am new to writing batch scripts, but would like to use this opportunity to learn.

I have been able to make this sample code work for a single file when I rename a file to test.csv, but it would be preferred if there was a "Wild Card" for file name I could use.

```
@echo off
set "csv=test.csv"
more +17 "%csv%" >"%csv%.new"
move /y "%csv%.new" "%csv%" >nul
```

File itself is updated to NOT have the first 17 lines and renames named as it is started.

Comment: Open a Command Prompt window, enter `for /?`, and read the usage information.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverFlow. Please take the [Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). 
Please read, [How to ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).
Also please read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try like this :

```
@echo off

for %%a in (*.csv) do (
    more +17 "%%a" >"%%a.new"
    move /y "%%a.new" "%%a" >nul
)
```

Comment: While testing out both of these suggestions I have found that both processes get stuck when a file exceeds 65,534 rows of data? I am being presented with -- More (29%) --

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example based upon the `For /?` output, mentioned in my comment.

This one works directly at the Command Prompt:

```bat
For %A In (*.csv)Do @More +17 "%A">"%A.new"&&Move /Y "%A.new" "%A">Nul
```

And this is the batch file version:

```bat
@For %%A In (*.csv)Do @More +17 "%%A">"%%A.new"&&Move /Y "%%A.new" "%%A">Nul
```

The command above is almost identical to the other answer provided. The only 'real' difference is the use of the `&&` conditional operator, which should only run the `Move` command if the previous command, `More`, is successful. Whilst it's an unlikely scenario that the `More` command should fail, I would still suggest implementing the safety of the conditional statement. *If you do not feel that you require that additional feature, feel free to select [SachaDee](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2414894/sachadee)'s answer, (if it solves your issue).*

Comment: I followed your original guidance and had been struggling to properly build the syntax. I was being thrown in off in the help by the /D /F following the for. Thank you for this second solution as it worked like a charm.

Comment: Both styles do great unless the file exceeds 65534 rows. Then it just sits and goes not further?

Comment: The file size issue is due to the commands, `More` and `Move`, and method you chose and used. Your question, as asked, has been answered, your issue is outside of the scope of your question and, as such, should be asked as a new question.